# How to delete a jar file opened using URL#openConnection()?

Tags: java

I have a small function which essentially takes a java.net.URL, reads the file and closes it. I want to delete the file after the read is over. However, I am not able to delete it even through the windows explorer, while the process is running. I get the error message that the file is still in use. This works good for normal files but not for jar files. Am I supposed to do something different? Here is the code snippet I am using.

Updated code snippet:

```
public static void tryPreOpenConnection(URL url, File file) throws IOException {
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
    stream.read();
    stream.close();
    System.out.println("Deleted: " + file.delete());
    connection = null;
    stream = null;
    System.gc();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // do nothing
    }
    System.out.println("Deleted: " + file.delete());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you remembered to close the URL connection?

Also, can you post a larger code snippet so we can see the context?

Comment: I don't see a close function on the URL connection.

Comment: My program is a long running program and I want to make sure that the jar file could be deleted after it is used. So, I tried out a small testcase where I just open the connection, close the stream, even null the connection, and then try to delete the file. I tried deleting the file manually and programatically.

Comment: Your code above doesn't show us what is happening to the File object outside of the method.  If another stream referencing the file is still open, the file delete() call will fail.

Comment: The file is just passed to try out delete

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Commons Virtual File System](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/).

Few days ago I have one problem with internal caching in the HttpURLConnection (implementation). URLConnection is awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to http://www.genevski.com/2010/04/javaneturl-and-jarurlconnection-may.html. I found the problem. Unless the **useCaches** property is set to false, the connection seems to be holding up the file. I could manage to get around this problem by setting this property or changing my code to something like

```
public static void tryPreOpenConnection(URL url, File file) throws IOException {
    JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    JarFile jar = connection.getJarFile();
    JarEntry entry = connection.getJarEntry();
    InputStream stream = jar.getInputStream(entry);
    stream.read();
    stream.close();
    jar.close();
    System.out.println("Deleted: " + file.delete()); // this works
}
```